# Error in time_of_day_base(x, x[["t_"]], include.crepuscule = include.crepuscule, : Please install package `maptools` first

Tags: r

I am regular working with the amt package and the function

```
time_of_day().
```

But since I refreshed my R version to 4.2.2 this function is not working anymore.

I also tried with the amt data and it is as well not working.

```
if(!require('amt')) {
  install.packages('amt')
  library('amt')
}

data(deer)`
deer |> time_of_day()`
```

```
Error in time_of_day_base(x, x[["t_"]], include.crepuscule = include.crepuscule,  : 
  Please install package `maptools` first.
```

But I have maptools installed. I searched everywhere but I don't know why it stopped suddenly working and how to solve this problem.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. After reading their package notation I noticed it says time_of_day is just "a convenience wrapper around suncalc::getSunlightTime". I did install.packages("suncalc") and re-ran the time_of_day line as is and it worked

Comment: Yes it is working with the package "suncalc". Thanks so much!